# how to fetch the element present inside Json Object through mongodb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb database, I unable to apply query to fetch all document with status CERTIFIED,I am using below document, please suggets any query like to fetch all document with "status":"CERTIFIED"

```
 { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("592fb37d57693963cca325e5"), 
        "json" : {
            "query_by_gtin_response:queryByGtinResponse" : {
                "productData" : {
                    "gtin" : "31212121212167", 
                    "productDataRecord" : {
                        "module" : [
                            {
                                "bpi:basicProductInformationModule" : {
                                    "xmlns:bpi" : "urn:gs1:tsd:basic_product_information_module:xsd:1", 
                                    "productName" : {
                                        "languageCode" : "en", 
                                        "value" : "test"
                                    }, 
                                    "brandNameInformation" : {
                                        "brandName" : {
                                            "value" : "test pub"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "product_tracking_information_module" : {
                                    "variantId" : {
                                        "value" : "31124ff0-4693-11e7-9492-01c27f5bdb71"
                                    }, 
                                    "status" : {
                                        "value" : "CERTIFIED"
                                    }, 
                                    "name" : {
                                        "value" : "admin@gmail.com"
                                    }, 
                                    "createdBy" : {
                                        "value" : "552f5b90b348147e03e49b62"
                                    }, 
                                    "createdDate" : {
                                        "value" : "2017-06-01T06:26:05.551Z"
                                    }, 
                                    "updatedBy" : {
                                        "value" : "552f5b90b348147e03e49b62"
                                    }, 
                                    "updatedDate" : {
                                        "value" : "2017-06-01T06:26:05.551Z"
                                    }, 
                                    "applicationId" : {
                                        "value" : "webapp"
                                    }, 
                                    "history" : {
                                        "createdDate" : {
                                            "value" : "2017-06-01T06:26:05.551Z"
                                        }, 
                                        "updatedDate" : {
                                            "value" : "2017-06-01T06:26:05.551Z"
                                        }, 
                                        "status" : {
                                            "value" : "CERTIFIED"
                                        }, 
                                        "updatedBy" : {
                                            "value" : "552f5b90b348147e03e49b62"
                                        }, 
                                        "createdBy" : {
                                            "value" : "552f5b90b348147e03e49b62"
                                        }, 
                                        "applicationId" : {
                                            "value" : "webapp"
                                        }, 
                                        "name" : {
                                            "value" : "admin@gmail.com"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function as your [$where operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#examples):

```
collection.find({ $where: function() {
    var productDataRecord = this.json["query_by_gtin_response:queryByGtinResponse"]["productData"]["productDataRecord"];
    var status = productDataRecord["module"][1]["product_tracking_information_module"].status;
    return (status.value == "CERTIFIED")
}})
```